# Cordova push notification not working when app is in background

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

I have implemented push notification in Cordova application by using following plugin

- https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

It's receiving notifications in application(but Not in notification area).
But when my app is in background it does not show any notification.

So it's working only when app in foreground.

So, I have 2 questions :

1. How to show received notification in notification area?
2. How to received notification even my app is in background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got my answer.

First go through GCM documentation, then I realize that I was not sending 'message' in 'data' parameter of push notification.

Comment: can you explain how to receive the notification in background

Comment: you don't have to do anything. Android will do it for you. but you just make sure when you are pushing notification from server `message` parameter should present.

Comment: Code examples would help you know. Where is this message parameter set since you also didnt know about  it.